# Classes which interpret any structure

Tags: model-theory

I'm afraid this question might be too localized, but I have no better place to ask it:

In the section [Classes which interpret any structure](http://books.google.com/books?id=Rf6GWut4D30C&lpg=PR9&ots=IcICZp40RQ&dq=wilfrid%2520hodges%2520classes%2520interpret&lr&pg=PA228#v=snippet&q=first%2520we%2520show%2520how%2520to%2520convert&f=false) of his *Model Theory* Hodges shows how each $L$-structure $B$ can be converted into a graph $A = \Delta(B)$, $L$ a first order language with finite signature.

He associates every element of $B$ with a so-called 5-tagged element $a$ of $A$. Likewise he associates the *i*-th symbol of the signature $S_i$ with a (*i*+6)-tagged element of $A$. For further details see Hodges, p. 228 ff.

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://epublius.de/mathoverflow/hodges.png)

The only question I have at this point is: Why isn't it enough to associate all the relation symbols with different 6-tagged (and 6-tagged *only*) elements of $A$? Why is it necessary - for his argument's sake - to distinguish them further by their "tag count"?

Comment: I haven’t got the book handy, but I suppose you need to be able to distinguish the relation symbols from each other by a (parameter-free) formula. If they were all $6$-tagged, they would be isomorphic, hence indistinguishable.

Comment: Perhaps one consideration is that by doing this you seem to make a graph with exactly the same automorphism group as the original structure. Otherwise, as Emil says, you might introduce automorphisms of the graph that do not correspond to any automorphism of the original structure, simply by moving the (nodes corresponding to the) relations rather than the nodes corresponding to the elements.

Comment: I think the goal is not the automorphism group, but interpretation of $B$ in $A$: for any sentence $\phi$, we have a $\phi^*$ such that $B\models\phi$ iff $A\models\phi^*$. But the point is the same: if `$B\models\forall x\,P(x)\land\neg\forall x\,Q(x)$`, we’d better make sure that the gadgets which are used in $A$ to read off the values of $P$ and $Q$ cannot be swapped by an automorphism, as otherwise we couldn’t interpret $\forall x\,P(x)$ and $\forall x\,Q(x)$ by a different formula.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you'd need a parameter. Emil, why not post as an answer? 

Comment: My question then is: Why is the distinguishability of the relations so important? I would find it consistent when the relations were treated on an equal footing as the elements.

Comment: Hans, the point is that you want to provide a translation of statements about the original structure into statements about the graph, and the definability of the nodes corresponding to the relations allows you to do so. The collection of nodes corresponding to the elements is definable, and so one can arrive at translations of any $L$-statement by quantifying over that collection, and expressing that a relation holds by referring to the definable property of being connected to certain tagged nodes in the way that is described. 

Comment: But the order of the relations (relation symbols) in the original structure is arbitrary, isn't it? Why then mimick it by ordering them in the graph?

Comment: When do I consider two structures with *n≥1* relations (of corresponding arities) isomorphic? When I can put the elements and the relations into 1:1 correspondence?

Comment: Hans, you really seem to be confused about basic definitions of a model and an isomorphism. Given a language (signature) $L$, an $L$-structure $\mathbf M$ is a set $M$ together with an assignment of an $n$-are relation $R^M$ to any $n$-ary relation symbol of $L$, and likewise for functions (which I’m going to ignore). An isomorphism of $\mathbf M$ and $\mathbf N$ is a bijection $f\colon M\to N$ such that $R^M(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ iff $R^N(f(a_1),\dots,f(a_n))$ for every $n$-ary relation symbol $R$ of $L$, and every $a_1,\dots,a_n\in M$.

Comment: So, no, you cannot permute the relations. Each relation is labelled with a fixed relation symbol which it is supposed to realize in the model. This is in perfect accordance with the main purpose of models, which is to be models *of first-order sentences*; the notion of isomorphism is defined so that it preserves validity of sentences. Permuting relations does not preserve validity of sentences. For example (using functions for a change), if you take a model $(M,+,\cdot)$ of Peano arithmetic and swap $+$ and $\cdot$, it will no longer be a model of Peano arithmetic, and (...)

Comment: ... in return it will satisfy funny formulas like `$\forall x,y,z\,(x+yz=(x+y)(x+z))$`.

Comment: @Emil: Isn't there a definition of "structure" without the symbols or interpretion: just a tupel consisting of a set and relations on it? 

Comment: @Emil: I found such a definition: in Suppe's Introduction to Logic, p. 252: *a simple relational structure as an ordered couple consisting of a set and a binary relation*. I find it interesting that he doesn't define "isomorphic" for structures with two relations of the same arity. How would he have done it?

Comment: Hans, is there any actual question you want to ask, or do you just want to argue with Hodges that he is using a wrong notion of an isomorphism?

Comment: He = Suppes? Is this what you think: that Suppes is using a wrong notion of isomorphism? Or isn't it just another one? How can it be that a respectable logician like Suppes use a *wrong* notion of isomorphism?

Comment: Might this be my lesson learned: There are two definitions of "structure" - one model-theoretic, with names, one set-theoretic, without names - which give rise to two notions of "isomorphism"?

Comment: I was not talking about Suppes, but Hodges. I have no idea what's in Suppes' book, but your description of it does not seem to support your argument in any way. If there is only one relation, then your definition of isomorphism coincides with the standard one. I don't know why would Suppes define isomorphism only for some special case and not in general, but this certainly does not imply that if he defined in in general he would define it your way.

Comment: In any case, this is a pointless discussion. There may be contexts where your notion of isomorphism is helpful, but that has nothing to with the question whether Hodges' proof can be modified to use this notion and still prove the original statement that Hodges is proving. So: what is the actual statement that he is proving?

Comment: a) To make things clear: I didn't want to argue that Hodges is wrong, of course not. I just want to *understand*. b) It seems to be a matter of fact that Suppes defines "structure" different from the model-theorists. c) Concerning a general definition of isomorphism he says: *A satisfactory definition of isomorphism is difficult if not impossible to formulate. The standard general practice is to formulate a separate definition for each general kind of ordered n-tuple.* 

Comment: How does Suppes define structure, then? A simple relational structure is not a general structure. A simple relational structure is a structure with only one relation symbol, and if you have only one symbol, then you cannot gain or lose anything by permuting the set of labels of your symbols, since that set is a singleton.

Comment: Anyway, I looked up theorem 5.5.1 in Hodges, and he is constructing a sentence in the language of graphs whose models are biinterpretable with the class of all $L$-structures (of size >1) for a given finite language $L$. The most salient feature of interpretations is that they preserve validity of formulas, and as formulas contain relation symbols, their validity is not preserved by relabelling the relations. I already wrote this above, including an example of such a non-preserved sentence. Which part of that explanation was unclear?

Comment: He defines structure by structure. He would have defined "double relational structure" as a tupel of a set and two binary relations. For me it's open how he would have defined isomorphism for "double relational structures", he's not explicit about this (as far as I can see).

Comment: @Emil: Sorry, your explanation *was* clear, I didn't want to argue, just bring into play a different notion of "structure", which I stumbled upon only *after* I asked my question, but which seemed to be related to my question. Sorry for the lengthy discussion I involved you into.

Comment: A tuple is not a set, but a sequence. Suppes' definition as you presented it is equivalent to the usual one, except that the relations are labelled only implicitly by their position in the tuple, not by an explicit symbol. That's a quite common simplification of notation for structures in finite signature.

Comment: Believe me or not: That's exactly what I recognized some minutes ago, while thinking things over.

Comment: Interesting enough, that this simplification is almost never made explicit. Even Hodges suggests that structures are to be considered as ordered tuples which is superfluous when the relations etc. are explicitly named.